# if excel formula true false function

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

i am trying to use the if function in excel but i am stuck.

if cell d7 has text "working" leave blank, if any other text put an X in the cell.

Can anyone help with the correct formula please.

ive tried the if function but can't get it right.

Comment: If you mean *contains* as in *"I am working today."*, you could use something like `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("working",D7)),"","X")`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
=IF(D7="working","","X")
```